# Page height being effected by jQuery image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building a site that uses a jQuery image gallery. You can see an example [here](http://247896-7.temp-dns.com/tenants/property-details/Bradley).

For some reason, when the gallery changes images, or when you manually change images, the page height seems to be 'flickering' for want of a better word. It seems as though the page height is being increased by the new image, and then very quickly being reduced back to its original height.

Does anyone have any ideas on what's causing this and how to fix it?

As always, any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: I don't know what is flickering. I tried interacting with the gallery but everything looks good.

Comment: Well, it looks like it's animating from 282px to 282px... I don't know if that will mess with your page height or not. Regardless of that, galleria is a somewhat heavy script; you might look into alternatives that would be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this google code contain with jquery.lightbox-0.5.css

[code.google.com/p/imdametadata/source/browse/trunk/guidelines/documents/web/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css](http://code.google.com/p/imdametadata/source/browse/trunk/guidelines/documents/web/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css)